# How do I pass function parameters from a variable with concatenated html+object values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a function that automatically fills a twitter feed div on the page with the ID of #feed.

This is the problem code.

```
          function createTweets(item, index) {
            let text = '<div class="tweet">'
              '<img class="float" src=\"' + json[index].user.profile_image_url_https + '\" alt="">'
              '<span class="float name"><strong>' + json[index].user.name + '</strong></span>'
              '<span class="username float">@' + json[index].user.screen_name + ' · </span>'
              '<span class="postTime float"></span>'
              '<p class="text">' + json[index].text + '</p>'
              '<hr>'
            '</div>';

            $('#feed').append(text);
          }
json.forEach(createTweets);
```

I imagine the issue is quite simple but I struggle to figure it out. Everything else works fine as if I simply the text variable to

```
let text = json[index].user.name // or any other combination
```

works absolutely fine.

Any help much appreciated.

**Update:**

I'm sorry if this is hard to understand, I don't know how to explain it any better.

I am trying to create a very simple twitter feed that gets the home_timeline endpoint contents and displays only the tweets with a favourite count of > 2.

PHP code:

```
<?php 

    require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    $consumerkey = "?";
    $consumersecret = "?";
    $access_token = "?";
    $access_token_secret = "?I";

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
    $content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

    $obj = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline");

    $len = count((array)$obj);

    if (gettype($obj) == 'object')
    {
      print_r($obj->errors);
    } elseif (gettype($obj) == 'array')
    {
      $p = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) 
        {
          if ($obj[$i]->favorite_count > 2) 
          {
            $favouriteTweets[$p] = $obj[$i];
            $p++;
          } 
        } 
    }


    ?>
```

html/css

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style type="text/css">

        html {
          font-size: 62.5%;
        }



        h1 {
          margin-top: 15px;
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }

        #feed {
          margin-top: 40px;
        }

        .tweet {
          border: 1px solid black;
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 50%;
          height: 100px;
        }

        .tweet img {
          margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .name {
          margin: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
          font-size: 1.75em;
        }

        .float {
          float: left;
        }

        .username {
          margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
          color: #8C8D8F;
          font-size: 1.3em;
        }

        .postTime {
          margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
          font-size: 1.3em;
        }

        .text {
          position: relative;
          top: -20px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          clear:both;
          width: 70%;
          font-size: 1.5em;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>



    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>If this was my feed, I'd have anorexia.</h1>

        <div id="feed">
            <div class="tweet">
              <img class="float" src="<? echo $favouriteTweets[0]->user->profile_image_url_https; ?>" alt="">
              <span class="float name"><strong><? echo $favouriteTweets[0]->user->name ?></strong></span>
              <span class="username float">@<? echo $favouriteTweets[0]->user->screen_name; ?> · </span>
              <span class="postTime float"></span>
              <p class="text"><? echo $favouriteTweets[0]->text; ?></p>
              <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        var json = <? echo json_encode($favouriteTweets); ?>;

          function createTweets(item, index) {
            let text = '<div class="tweet">'
              '<img class="float" src=\"json[index].user.profile_image_url_https + '\" alt="">'
              '<span class="float name"><strong>json[index].user.name</strong></span>'
              '<span class="username float">@' + json[index].user.screen_name + ' · </span>'
              '<span class="postTime float"></span>'
              '<p class="text">' + json[index].text + '</p>'
              '<hr>'
            '</div>';

            $('#feed').append(text);
          }
```

Finally, these are the errors I am getting in my Google Console.

running json.forEach(createTweets); returns

```
undefined
```

which I assume is because it is not pass the incremental "index" (0,1,2,3 etc) parameter of forEach(item, index) to createTweets(item, index) and then to the object array variable 'text' for example json[index].user.name;

if I remove all of the concatenation in the text variable and simply have it as

```
let text = json[index].user.name
```

it returns the value I expect which is the user.name at each index point in the json array.

Comment: I am not getting what is the issue here?

Comment: The index parameters in the text variable that is getting passed to or from  json.forEach(createTweets);  in the first paragraph of code is not working. However in the second section of code, if I remove all the badly written concatenation which I want to work, it works fine.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not getting what you are saying. Can you update your post with some examples that might help to understand your issue better? Or maybe add a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) to show your issue with some hard-coded data for `json` variable.

Comment: @palaѕн I have updated the question

Comment: Why are you not using the `item` argument? That should be the same as `json[index]` but less verbose. `json.forEach()` always returns undefined because it's not meant to return anything; it's just a helper function for iterating over the array.

Comment: Your `createTweet` function doesn't do much: it assigns `'<div class="tweet">'` to `text` and then has a few lines of unassigned string manipulation. You need to add `+` between those lines if you want to concatenate them together.

Comment: woah duh, thank you very much. I have been staring at this for too long I missed the extra pluses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating literal strings is so 2014 -- use [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax instead. As far as what's wrong...you haven't explained exactly what that was. From what code is provided, it should work unless the data being processed is faulty. There's no example of a JSON -- it would help us to help you if we knew how the variable `json` is structured.

---

The following demo is plain JavaScript. I guessed as to how `json` is structured.

#### Demo

```js
let json = [
  {user: {name:"zer0", alias: "zer00ne", img: "https://i.ibb.co/Hdyh0V0/wa2813224.png"}, text: "I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail."},
{user: {name: "Dyn", alias: "Dyneskye", img: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bdb83995e21f4272dc5e8253f8137f1?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"}, text: "How do I pass function parameters from a variable with concatenated html+object values?"}
];

function createTweets(array) {
  const feed = document.querySelector('#feed');
  array.forEach(item => {
    let html = `<figure class="tweet">
      <img class="avatar" src="${item.user.img}" alt="avatar" width='100'>
      <section class='nfo'>
      <fieldset>
      <legend class="username">
      ${item.user.name}</legend>
      <i class="useralias">
      @${item.user.alias}</i>
      </fieldset>
      <time class="timestamp">
        ${new Date(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) * 1000).toLocaleString()}</time>
      </section>
      <figcaption class="message">
      ${item.text}</figcaption>
      </figure>`;
    feed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  });
}

createTweets(json);
```

```css
:root,
body {
  font: 400 4vh/1.5 Verdana;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.tweet {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge #000;
}

.avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

.nfo {
  align-self: start;
  flex: 0 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.username {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.useralias {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.timestamp {
  display: block;
  font-family: consolas;
  margin: 0 5px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.message {
  flex: 1.5 0;
}
```

```html
<main id='feed'></main>
```

Comment: This was extremely informative thank you. I am a beginner as you can probably tell

Comment: You're very welcome. TBH it was difficult to tell that you were a beginner because I saw code that should work if the data structure was correct. I didn't see any edits or comments until after I posted my answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your multiline 'ht'
'ml'. This doesn't work. You forgot pluses! The ES6 way is:

```js
function createTweets(item, index) {
            let text = `<div class="tweet">
              <img class="float src=\"json[index].user.profile_image_url_https + '\" alt="">
              <span class="float name"><strong>json[index].user.name</strong></span>
              <span class="username float">@ ${json[index].user.screen_name} · </span>
              <span class="postTime float"></span>
              <p class="text"> ${json[index].text} .</p>
              <hr>
            </div>`;

            $('#feed').append(text);
          }
```

Look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals